# Centering a JMenuItem in a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

What I want to do is to center the JMenuItem elements inside the JPopupMenu. This is how they currently appear
[image]

I would like them to be in the center instead of the left side.

Here are some parts of my code

```
    JButton lvlBtn = new JButton("Level"); //For the button
    JPopupMenu pmenu = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem easyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Easy");
    JMenuItem mediumMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Medium");
    JMenuItem hardMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Hard");

    lvlBtn.setBounds(750, 20, 280, 50); //Setting a location for the button

    //Making an ActionListener for the button
    ActionListener btnAction=new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                //This will make the popup menu appear


                Component b=(Component)ae.getSource();

               // Taking the location of the button on the screen
               Point p=b.getLocationOnScreen();

               // this - current frame
               // 0,0 where the popup will initially appear
               pmenu.show(this,0,0);

               // Changing the location of the JPopupMenu and placing it
               // below the lvlBtn
               pmenu.setLocation(p.x,p.y+b.getHeight());
            }
        };
    lvlBtn.addActionListener(btnAction);

    //Setting a size for each JMenuItem
    easyMenuItem.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 20));
    mediumMenuItem.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 20));
    hardMenuItem.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 20));


    //Adding menu items in popup menu
    pmenu.add(easyMenuItem);
    pmenu.add(mediumMenuItem);
    pmenu.add(hardMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the `JMenuItem` API.

`JMenuItem` extends from `AbstractButton`.

`AbstractButton` is the base class for Swing components like `JButton`, `JCheckBox`, `JMenuItem`. As such it provides methods to customize the display of the text, icon etc.

Start with:

```
setHorizontalAlignment(...)
```

But check out the other methods available for future reference as well.